# Join multiple tables without having common key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am working on a project about creating the ETL process but stuck at 1 problem, Where I need to insert data into the Dimension table by using 3 different Tables without having a common key by which I can join tables. I have tried to approach this problem with CTE but no use.

Earthquake Table with Data

[image]
[Table Earthquake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky2Y7.png)

City Table with Data

[image]
[Table City](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz2FK.png)

Country Table with Data

[image]
[Country Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX4Zs.png)

**What I am trying to do **
I need to find the City, Country and World Region where Earthquake happened and store resulting values in different Tables. 
So, By using a formula that calculates the distance between the provided Locations. First Location I am taking from Earthquake Table and Second Location from City Latitude and Longitude.

```
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(E.Latitude) ) * cos( radians( C.Latitude ) ) *  cos( radians( C.Longitude) - radians(E.Longitude) ) + sin( radians(E.Latitude) ) * sin( radians( C.Latitude ) ) ) )   < 100
```

Here `C.Latitude` is City Latitude and `E.Latitude` is Latitude where it occurred.

This is my unfruitful CTE approach.

```
WITH Test_CTE (
    Latitude
    ,Longitude
    ,City
    ,Country
    ,Region
    ,Place
    )
AS (
    SELECT E.Latitude
        ,E.Longitude
        ,C.City
        ,C.Country
        ,Cntry.Region
        ,Cast(E.place AS VARCHAR(50))
    FROM Earthquake AS E
        ,(
            SELECT Latitude
                ,Longitude
                ,Country
                ,City
            FROM City
            ) AS C
        ,(
            SELECT Country
                ,Region
            FROM Country
            ) AS Cntry
    WHERE (6371 * acos(cos(radians(E.Latitude)) * cos(radians(C.Latitude)) * cos(radians(C.Longitude) - radians(E.Longitude)) + sin(radians(E.Latitude)) * sin(radians(C.Latitude)))) < 100
        AND Cntry.Country = C.Country
    )
SELECT *
FROM Test_CTE
```

Which Produces this Result

[image]
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AHRA.png)

Note: Column other then City repeats too many times.

My Expectations: Each row from Earthquake Table has the only 1 closest corresponding City, Country from City, Region from Country table and Place from Earthquake table.

I haven't Worked with tables without having a common key, so I have no idea why and what causing this issue.
Can someone help me? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT  E.Latitude
        ,E.Longitude
        ,C.City
        ,C.Country
        ,Cntry.Region
        ,Cast(E.place AS VARCHAR(50))
FROM Earthquake E
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 City
    FROM City
    WHERE (6371 * acos(cos(radians(E.Latitude)) * cos(radians(C.Latitude)) * cos(radians(C.Longitude) - radians(E.Longitude)) + sin(radians(E.Latitude)) * sin(radians(C.Latitude)))) < 100
    ORDER BY (6371 * acos(cos(radians(E.Latitude)) * cos(radians(C.Latitude)) * cos(radians(C.Longitude) - radians(E.Longitude)) + sin(radians(E.Latitude)) * sin(radians(C.Latitude)))) ASC
) City
INNER JOIN City C
    ON City.City = C.City
INNER JOIN Country Cntry
    ON C.Country = Cntry.Country
```

The idea is to use `CROSS APPLY` to get the closest city to specific earthquake. Тhen using `INNER JOIN` get the data.

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to list records which has not got closest to 100 city.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gotqn, it wasn't working quite but after a little adjustment. It works Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

Use `Split String UDF` to split Place column of `EarthQuake` table.

```
;with CTE as
(
select EQ.*,SScol from EarthQuake EQ
cross apply(select col split_string(Place,' ')SS )SS
)
,CTE1 as
(
select Ct.*,c.country,c.city from CTE ct
left join City C on ct.col=c.country
)
,CTE2 as
(
select Ct.*,c.country,c.city from CTE1 ct
left join City C on ct.col=c.city
)
```

This will give you idea to strengthen your `City` and `Country` table.

I don't know whether `Country` table is require or not.

Or you can run to see how many data are missing which do not have any `city` or `country`,
and WHY ?

This way you can create alogrithm.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Harsh Kumar.